# Vulkan SDK setup: vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties failed to find the VK_KHR_surface extension

Tags: vulkan

I tried to run the Vulkan cube example after downloading the Vulkan SDK but get the following

```
 vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties failed to find the VK_KHR_surface extension.
 Do you have a compatible Vulkan installable client driver (ICD) installed?
```

I have a Nvidia GK107M [Geforce GT 755M] graphics card.
Regarding the graphics driver, the output of 
    `lshw -c video | grep 'configuration'` is

```
configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
```

And when I see through the driver manager it shows Nvidia-352 graphics driver. Earlier I was using Nouveau display driver which I disabled thinking that it might not support Vulkan and the Nvidia driver would. But still the same thing persists.

On running `.\vulkaninfo` I got a message saying that vulkan instance creation failed with `VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER`.

P.S: I am using the latest Vulkan SDK releases today only. I am going to try the older SDK versions. Maybe they would work.
P.P.S: I have run into a black /blank screen issue after updating Nvidia driver to 370 and rebooting.

Comment: "*I am also not able to run `vulkaninfo` from the terminal*" Well, that sounds very much like you do not have a Vulkan driver installed. Did you install one from NVIDIA?

Comment: Hi Nicol. Let me edit the question. Thanks for the quick response. I did not know that vulkaninfo would be an executable. I was able to run it. I am including its output in the edit.

Comment: And as far as I know Nvidia drivers support Vulkan. So I am confused.

Comment: I have confirmed from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver) that Nvidia Geforce GT 755M GPU supports Vulkan.

Comment: From your link, v352 driver is clearly from way before Vulkan. Did you use the driver installer from that page or from one of those chronically outdated distro package repos?

Comment: BTW, SDK shouldn't matter that much. It is intended for developers. Vulkan apps should run without it if I am not mistaken (at least on Windows they do).

Comment: BTW2, v367 seems to be marked stable, so try that one if the 370 fails. Also might not be trivial to install these non-repo ones on linuxes — read the README.

Comment: Yes. I gave up trying to set up Vulkan on my laptop. I have something called Nvidia optimus due to which I faced a hell lot of problems updating to v367 and using the GPU and finally I used Bumblebee for optimus linux support. But bumblebee does not support Vulkan.

Comment: One can read [here](http://coderofworlds.com/before-buying-a-laptop-check-if-it-has-nvidia-optimus-its-purpose-is-infuriate-you/) about how infuriating optimus is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimus. Well, there you have it. To quote directly from the driver package documents:

> Some designs incorporating supported GPUs may not be compatible with the NVIDIA Linux driver: in particular, notebook and all-in-one desktop designs with switchable (hybrid) or Optimus graphics will not work if means to disable the integrated graphics in hardware are not available. Hardware designs will vary from manufacturer to manufacturer, so please consult with a system's manufacturer to determine whether that particular system is compatible.

So, you need to disable it (in BIOS) if possible (as it says above).

Or get updated driver from the notebook manufacturer (Well, as much chance as seeing Android update on chinatablet. If they even bother with linux support.).

Or expect exactly the kind of problems and hackery with no guaranteed success you face.

The v352 driver you have wouldn't support Vulkan. It is older than Vulkan.
Nouveau to my knowledge doesn't support Vulkan (yet) either.

Comment: So, if I move from linux to windows would I be able to use Vulkan?

Comment: @Deven No guarantees. Also I have no means to test that (someone else?) But it says "Notebooks supporting Hybrid Power technology are not supported (NVIDIA Optimus technology is supported)." Whatever that means...

Comment: Yes I also couldn't understand that part.

Comment: Anyway, I would try but I would have to uninstall linux and switch to w Windows which I don't particularly like as it can all be for nothing if same thing happens with windows.

Comment: @Devon I take it you cannot disable the technology from BIOS (set only the dedicated card)? IMO such technologies are usually added more to reduce notebook's lifetime and get rid of old/pre-negotiated GPU stock, than to help with battery life or anything anyway.

Comment: Yes, I did not find any such option.

Comment: Update: I switched to Windows 7 and was able to use Vulkan.

Answer (score 1):

There's 3 places that the Vulkan loader looks to find a Linux driver's JSON definition file:

- /etc/vulkan/icd.d
- /usr/share/vulkan/icd.d
- And wherever you define "VK_DRIVERS_PATH" to.

If you don't have a JSON in one of those locations for your Nvidia driver that would be a problem.

Secondly, if you do have the JSON file, but it's "library_path" entry doesn't point to a valid driver, that would also not work.

Try looking for those files.

Comment: Hey thanks fot the answer but I think the problem was with my drivers only. Using the lates vulkan supported Nvidia stable driver should have worked if there had not been the optimus problem. As the message vulkan info gave was incompatible driver.